# What's the best way to verify that two jar files are the same irregardless of the version in the pom file and other metadata?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I would like to generate a checksum over a jar-file while ignoring its metadata, such as the version number that was used (as present in the pom file) or the creation/modification date of the files it contains [1].

Effectively, I would like to have a hash that only changes if the underlying code has been altered. It should stay the same if f.e. build version 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 both contain the same class files and other resources such as images or config files.

What would be the best way to integrate something like this into the Maven build process?

[1] [Why does the same JAR file have different hash every time I build it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993329/why-does-the-same-jar-file-have-different-hash-every-time-i-build-it)

Comment: why would you re-release a library if you haven't changed anything?

Comment: The build contains several jar-files which all share the same version number. For regression testing it would be nice to know what needs to be re-tested and which parts remained the same in both versions.

Comment: Note that a test on A.jar might suddenly break if the version of a dependency B.jar has changed in the pom. The same source code does not guarantee the same behaviour.

Comment: Of course! I forgot to mention that I am talking about a manual test here and this question assumes that people are aware of the underlying dependency graph.